# obtain the employee names who made a higher salary in March 2018 than their average monthly salary for all previous months

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

select * from emp1;

| EMP_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10100 | Marcos | Bisset |
| 10101 | Kate | Perez |
| 10102 | Carlos | Casco |

select * from payment history;

| EMP_ID | PAY_TYPE | AMT_PAID | PAY_DATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10100 | monthly pay | 12000 | 02-FEB-18 |
| 10101 | monthly pay | 2800 | 02-FEB-18 |
| 10102 | monthly pay | 1900 | 02-MAR-18 |
| 10101 | bonus | 1500 | 08-MAR-18 |
| 10102 | adjustment | 124 | 10-MAR-18 |

Please give answer using With Clause ( I got the question from internet .. but I am unable to solve this question

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What part of the task is it you are actually having problems with? What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Show your approach, and tell us where you need help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the salary for march and the average previous salary you can sum the salary for each employee and month and then use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MAX(e.first_name) AS first_name,
       MAX(e.last_name) AS last_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN month = DATE '2018-03-01' THEN pay END) AS march_pay,
       AVG(CASE WHEN month < DATE '2018-03-01' THEN pay END) AS avg_previous_pay
FROM   emp1 e
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT emp_id,
                TRUNC(pay_dated, 'MM') AS month,
                SUM(amt_paid) AS pay
         FROM   payment_history
         GROUP BY emp_id,
                TRUNC(pay_dated, 'MM')
       ) p
       ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE emp1 (EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 10100, 'Marcos', 'Bisset' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10101, 'Kate',   'Perez'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10102, 'Carlos', 'Casco'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE payment_history (EMP_ID, PAY_TYPE, AMT_PAID, PAY_DATED) AS
SELECT 10100, 'monthly pay', 12000, DATE '2018-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10101, 'monthly pay',  2800, DATE '2018-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10102, 'monthly pay',  1900, DATE '2018-03-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10101, 'bonus',        1500, DATE '2018-03-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10102, 'adjustment',    124, DATE '2018-03-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | MARCH_PAY | AVG_PREVIOUS_PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marcos | Bisset | *null* | 12000 |
| Kate | Perez | 1500 | 2800 |
| Carlos | Casco | 2024 | *null* |

To then find the employee with the higher salary in march than their previous average salary, you can use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(e.first_name) AS first_name,
       MAX(e.last_name) AS last_name
FROM   emp1 e
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT emp_id,
                TRUNC(pay_dated, 'MM') AS month,
                SUM(amt_paid) AS pay
         FROM   payment_history
         GROUP BY emp_id,
                TRUNC(pay_dated, 'MM')
       ) p
       ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN month = DATE '2018-03-01' THEN pay END)
        > AVG(CASE WHEN month < DATE '2018-03-01' THEN pay END)
```

Which outputs no rows as you can see from the previous data that Employees either have a higher average previous pay or they had no pay in one of the months; to get a result you need a larger data set where there is a row that actually matches the requirements.

---

Requiring a `WITH` clause is an artificial requirement that is not necessary to solve the problem; if you really must use it (*you do not need to*) then move the sub-query from the `INNER JOIN` into a sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH avg_pay (emp_id, month, pay) AS (
  <sub-query>
)
SELECT ...
FROM   emp1 e
       INNER JOIN avg_pay p
       ON ...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQD8Czy4)

Comment: You are great sir, so much better explanation .. really really Thank full to you,  I got a lot of knowledge from this .

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, step-by-step. Read comments within code.

```
with 
avg_sal as
  -- average salary per each employee
  (select emp_id, 
          avg(amt_paid) avg_sal
   from payment_history
   group by emp_id
  ),
march_sal as
  -- salary employee earned in March 2018
  (select emp_id, 
          amt_paid
   from payment_history
   where to_char(pay_dated, 'yyyymm') = '201803'
  )
select e.first_name
from emp1 e join avg_sal a on a.emp_id = e.emp_id
            join march_sal m on m.emp_id = e.emp_id
where m.amt_paid > a.avg_sal;
```

---

`WHERE` clause in `march_sal` CTE might need to be rewritten if there's an index on `pay_dated` column, as applying `to_char` function to it (the column) won't use that index. In that case, you'd use

```
WHERE pay_dated >= date '2018-03-01'
  AND pay_dated <  date '2018-04-01'
```

On the other hand, you might have a function-based index on `to_char(pay_dated, 'yyyymm')` - in that case, leave it *as is*.

Comment: @AbinashMandal The question asks "... than their average monthly salary for all previous months" whereas this compares it to "their average monthly salary for all months". You need to add a `WHERE` filter on the average.

Comment: @MT0 can you please post the answer with step by step guide ,